# Exception with the 2nd parameter of the DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime?

Tags: java, datetime

What do/can I pass as the 2 parameters of the `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle dateStyle, FormatStyle timeStyle)` method?  I tried as [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) **suggests** but I get this error.  I am assuming you understand that at DateTimeFormatter should be capable of formatting both a LocalDate and/or a LocalTime object, as the JavaDoc implies,  and I don't think I am misunderstanding that since the JavaDoc shows an example of it. :

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.time.format.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate pieDay = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.JANUARY, 23);
    LocalTime midnight = LocalTime.of(0,0);
    LocalDateTime pieTime = LocalDateTime.of(pieDay, midnight);

    DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT, 
        FormatStyle.SHORT);
    f2.format(pieDay); // Exception here at runtime
    f2.format(pieTime);
  }
}
```

Here is my sandbox for experimenting with this: https://repl.it/JzHb/28   but please run your own version of this code snippet to validate your answer before giving it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException:
  Unsupported field: ClockHourOfAmPm
```

Comment: It says that method `getDefault()` doesn't exist, and it doesn't. Why do you believe that [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) has such a method?

Comment: Sorry for that confusion. I updated my question.

Comment: Of course `f2.format(pieDay)` fails with `Unsupported field: ClockHourOfAmPm`, since **`LocalDate` doesn't have *time* fields**. If you want to format a date-only value, use `ofLocalizedDate()`.

Comment: My question is specifically about LocalDateTime, not LocalDate.  I have no such problem when applying the standard date formatting. A DateTime formatter should work on either Date or a Time object. My question is about this specific overloaded .ofLocalizedDateTime constructor.    I suspect the answer lies in using a Locale object, but I am not sure.

Comment: Your question, in it's current form, is *specifically* about the `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException`, which is caused by you using a *date+time formatter* but passing it a *date-only object*, as I explained in my previous comment. If that is not your problem, then clean up the question to clarify *what* your problem is. --- As for your question *"What do/can I pass as the 2nd parameter"*, you've already answered that yourself by passing one of the `FormatStyle` enum values. You simply choose which of the 4 is good for your need. I don't understand what more you need to know about that.

Comment: The problem I am asking becomes clear if you just try to run the code yourself.  This is why I provided a link to the executable code.  Sometimes a code snippet is better than 1000 words.

Comment: The code snippet in the link doesn't even compile, and was addressed in my first comment. The updated code in the question fails with `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException`, and was addresses in my second comment (use of `LocalDate`). Now you say that running the code would make the problem clear, but the only thing clear when running the code is that `LocalDate` is the cause of your problem, but you say your question is not about `LocalDate`, so obviously running the code does not make the question clear.

Comment: I'll try once again to update my question with further clarification.

Comment: I understand your question, but you don't seem to understand what I've been telling you, so let me try a different way. If you create a `LocalTime` object for 9 AM, then create a `DateTimeFormatter` to format into a string with date values like day-of-month, it will fail, because a `LocalTime` doesn't have such a value. Equivalent human conversation: "At 9 AM". "What day?". "**Unknown**, all I know is 9 AM". Same goes the other way. `LocalDate.of(2017, Month.JANUARY, 23)`. What time? Unknown, aka `Unsupported field: ClockHourOfAmPm`.

Comment: @Andreas next time please answer in an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, the answer to my question is that I assumed that a DateTimeFormatter would work on any of the 3 combinations :

- A LocalDate object
- A LocalTime object
- A LocalDateTime object

But, it appears that the DateTimeFormatter is not capable of formatting a LocalDate or LocalTime

```
LocalDate pieDay = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.JANUARY, 23);
LocalTime midnight = LocalTime.of(0,0);
LocalDateTime pieTime = LocalDateTime.of(pieDay, midnight);

DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL, FormatStyle.SHORT);

//System.out.println(f2.format(midnight)); // this throws exception
//System.out.println(f2.format(pieDay)); // this throws exception

f2.format(pieTime);  //  this line works
```

This was not obvious from the JavaDoc as I expected it to work in a flexible manner, like the old java.text.DateFormat class.

Comment: Wrong!!! `DateTimeFormatter` does work with all 3 classes, as long as you don't make it ask for information that is not available. You are calling `ofLocalizedDateTime` (**DateTime**), which means it will format any `java.time` object that has both a **Date** and a **Time**, such as `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime`. If you instead use `ofLocalizedDate` (**Date** only), then it will not ask the object being formatted for a time-of-day, and can also format a `LocalDate` object, in addition to the three already mentioned.

Comment: I already covered this in [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535747/exception-with-the-2nd-parameter-of-the-datetimeformatter-oflocalizeddatetime?noredirect=1#comment78073259_45535747): "`f2.format(pieDay)` fails with `Unsupported field: ClockHourOfAmPm`, since `LocalDate` doesn't have *time* fields. If you want to format a date-only value, use `ofLocalizedDate()`". --- The javadoc is correct:: `DateTimeFormatter` *can* format `LocalDate` objects, **if you use it right**.